# Driving in Norway with a US driving license

Tags: car-rentals, driving-licenses, norway

Can I rent and drive a car in Norway with a valid US (California) driving license?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, but for no more than 3 months.

Source: 
http://www.vegvesen.no/en/Driving+licences/About+Driving+licences/Foreign+driving+licences+in+Norway

http://www.vegvesen.no/en/Driving+licences/About+Driving+licences/Foreign+driving+licences+in+Norway/Issued+outside+the+EU+EEA